# How do I receive a string from a dynamic link?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a dynamic Link set up where you can share the the link with people like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Join my group for Lesn");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://y28rt.app.goo.gl/?link=https://Lesn.com/joinGroup&apn=c.kristofer.jax2[&amv=21]&groupUid=" + groupUid);
    startActivity(intent);
```

As you can see in the link

> "https://y28rt.app.goo.gl/?link=https://Lesn.com/joinGroup&apn=c.kristofer.jax2[&amv=21]&groupUid=" + groupUid

I put extra data which is

> groupUid=" + groupUid)

My question is How do I receive that string from the link using this

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    Uri deeplink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null){
                        deeplink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    }


                }
            });
```

> Edit

So my problem was actually putting in the wrong value for my deeplink. Now I've got it to work but my other problem still persists. Using deeplink.getQueryParameter("groupUid") it returns a null when I try to log the value.

Comment: Any luck here??

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque not yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to get parameter from a deepLink, using Uri method

```
String group = deeplink.getQueryParameter("groupUid");
```

Before that, to attach a parameter to dynamic link of Firebase, you must add parameter to the main link before you generate dynamic link

```
private void attachParameter(String groupUid) {
    Uri link = Uri.parse("https://Lesn.com/joinGroup")
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("groupUid", groupUid)
        .build();
    generateDynamicLink(link.toString());
}


private void generateDynamicLink(String link) {
    Uri dynamicLink = Uri.parse("https://y28rt.app.goo.gl")
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("link", link)
        .appendQueryParameter("apn", "c.kristofer.jax2")
        .build();

    Log.d(TAG, "generateDynamicLink: " + dynamicLink.toString());
}
```

However I recommend to use firebase lib instead of build dynamic link manual:

```
private void generateDynamicLinkWithLib(Uri link) {
    DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
        .setLink(link)
        .setDynamicLinkDomain("y28rt.app.goo.gl")
        .setAndroidParameters(new Builder().build())
        .setIosParameters(new IosParameters.Builder("c.kristofer.jax2")
            .build())
        .buildDynamicLink();

    Log.d(TAG, "generateDynamicLink: " + dynamicLink.getUri().toString());
}
```

Comment: hey what do you mean by generateDynamicLink(link)? I used this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) this

Comment: Yes. generateDynamicLink is a method follow thía guide. I just want to noted that parameters is attach to your link before you follow this guide.

Comment: I used this guide firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually to manually construct my dynamic link

Comment: That is all my code I generated from the guide I just copy pasted and changed some parts of it

Comment: I upddated my question please check it out!

Comment: I edit my answer with code example, please follow it

Comment: Last question how do I sent this through intent?